# Relationship between $\mathcal{L}_X(d(df))$ and $d(\mathcal{L}_X(df))$?

Tags: tensors, lie-derivative, exterior-derivative

I was thinking since $\mathcal{L}_X(d(df))$ = $\mathcal{L}_X(d(\omega))$ = $\mathcal{L}_X(g)$, where g is a (0,2)-tensor, and $d(\mathcal{L}_X(df)) = d(d\mathcal{L}_X(f)) = d(d(X[f])$ which is a two-form, so a (0,2)-tensor.

I don't know a lot about Lie derivatives, but I'm guessing the form stays the same, so are they both two-form and thus (0,2)-tensors?

But then $\mathcal{L}_X(df) = d(\mathcal{L}_Xf)$, so would also $d(\mathcal{L}_X(df)) = \mathcal{L}_X(d(df))$, and these two would actually be the same?

For clarification, $X$ is a vector field, $f$ is a function, and $\mathcal{L}_X$ and $d$ are Lie and exterior derivatives.

Comment: Yes, they are the same - and both equal to $0$: ${\cal L}_X$ and $d$ commute, and $d^2=0$.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure whether they commute in all cases, and completely overlooked the $d^2$ property. Is that zero a 0-form or 2-form?

Comment: If I understand your question, $d$ increases the degree of the form by $1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was wondering whether the $d^2=0$ is then a (0,2)-tensor or a scalar?

Comment: I don't think that it makes sense to say that $d$ (or $d^2$) is a tensor or a scalar. $d$ takes forms to forms. If I'm understanding your question, it's like asking whether a real valued function is a real number...

Comment: Yes, you're right. I meant the $d^2(f)=0$.